# Auto select two options based on drop-down list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code to select Salesman, State, and Office Number. What I want to be able to do is select the Salesman and have it auto select the State and Office Number for that person:

```
<label for="saleman">Senior Agent: </label>
<select id="salesman" name="salesman">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Tammy Sizemore">Tammy Sizemore</option>
        <option value="Ron Jeffries">Ron Jeffries</option>
        <option value="Tony Clark">Tony Clark</option>
        <option value="Mark Sengala">Mark Sengala</option>
        <option value="Judy Donato">Judy Donato</option>
        <option value="Mary Porter">Mary Porter</option>            
</select>

<label for="state">State: </label>
<select id="state" name="state">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
        <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
        <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
        <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
        <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
</select>

<label for="number">Office Number: </label>
<select id="number" name="number">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="A219">A219</option>
        <option value="A256">A256</option>
        <option value="G019">G019</option>
        <option value="G222">G222</option>
        <option value="Q161">Q161</option>
        <option value="Q341">Q341</option>
</select>
```

The problem I'm having is that it's a fairly complex decision process as to who belongs where. For example:
If I select 'Tammy Sizemore', I know she's in Kansas in office A256.
If I select 'Ron Jeffries', I know he's in Maine at office Q161.

I'm somewhat familiar with implementing jQuery or JavaScript. The page is being rendered by PHP. If it can be done in one of those, I'm fine. I just don't know how to implement this.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: It's a front end thing, so javascript is going to be what you use. You can create an event handler for the selection and then modify the other two depending on the value/option the user chose

Comment: Let user choose salesman, and on select make an AJAX request to your database and get his/her state and number. Update fields accordingly

Comment: I understand the concept needed however, I don't have the experience to WRITE the JavaScript/jQuery needed but if it's already out there, I can make the code work.

Comment: You have 7 persons but 6 locations and 6 O.Num. How would you explain this - and interconnect them? A join (connection) less to many (or many to less) - unless being random - will always favorite the first one in alphabetical order (or HTML appearance).

Comment: i.e: let's say that Mary and Jerry are both in Ohio, right, it would not be fair for Jenny to always be the one that matches that location - first.

Comment: I took one of the names off the list. It IS a one-to-one-to-one relationship with Name/State/Office Number. My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the work-around I came up with (in case someone else finds this handy):

When setting up the drop-down list, I combined the three elements (Name, State, and Office Number) into a single `value` but only showed the Salesman name.

```
<label for="saleman">Senior Agent: </label>
<select id="salesman" name="salesman">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Tammy Sizemore,Kansas,A256">Tammy Sizemore</option>
        <option value="Ron Jeffries,Maine,Q161">Ron Jeffries</option>
        <option value="Tony Clark,West Virginia,G019">Tony Clark</option>
        <option value="Mark Sengala,Ohio,Q341">Mark Sengala</option>
        <option value="Judy Donato,Iowa,A219">Judy Donato</option>
        <option value="Mary Porter,Pennsylvania,G222">Mary Porter</option>
</select>
```

Then, when I needed to split them back into separate fields, I used `explode`.

```
$sr_agent = $_POST['salesman'];
$sa = explode(',', $sr_agent);

$agent_name = $sa[0];
$agent_state = $sa[1];
$agent_office = $sa[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using the value attribute as you did in your work-around solution, as you're basically using the value attribute for something other than its intended use.  You can use custom data attributes that are perfect for this...

```js
// cache the state & office elements so we don't have to search the DOM every time
var $state = $("#state");
var $office = $("#office");

$("#salesman").on("change", function() {

  // find the selected option
  var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
  
  // get the associated state and office...
  var state = $selected.data("state");
  var office = $selected.data("office");
  
  // set the dropdowns
  $state.val(state);
  $office.val(office);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="saleman">Senior Agent: </label>
<select id="salesman" name="salesman">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Tammy Sizemore" data-state="Kansas" data-office="A256">Tammy Sizemore</option>
    <option value="Ron Jeffries" data-state="Maine" data-office="Q161">Ron Jeffries</option>
    <option value="Tony Clark" data-state="West Virginia" data-office="G019">Tony Clark</option>
    <option value="Mark Sengala" data-state="Ohio" data-office="Q341">Mark Sengala</option>
    <option value="Judy Donato" data-state="Iowa" data-office="A219">Judy Donato</option>
    <option value="Mary Porter" data-state="Pennsylvania" data-office="G222">Mary Porter</option>
</select>

<label for="state">State: </label>
<select id="state" name="state">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
    <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
    <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
    <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
    <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
</select>

<label for="office">Office Number: </label>
<select id="office" name="office">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="A219">A219</option>
    <option value="A256">A256</option>
    <option value="G019">G019</option>
    <option value="G222">G222</option>
    <option value="Q161">Q161</option>
    <option value="Q341">Q341</option>
</select>
```